# Difference between TCP_INFO tcpi_lost and tcpi_retrans

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

To my understanding

TCP_INFO tcpi_lost parameter is the counter for the TCP packet loss.

TCP_INFO tcpi_retrans parameter is the counter for the TCP Retransmission count.

If so, what is different between packet loss and packet retransmission count.

Packet loss in TCP leads to packet retransmission. Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcpi_lost counts all pockets that are lost, meaning if you send 10 pocket and have 5 pocket lost in transition it will tell you that you have 5 pocket lost, only if pocket is sent successfully will it be accounted for (meaning count will be decreased)
tcpi_retrans counts all pockets that are resent again, so if you have 10 pockets 5 were lost but only 3 were resent it will show that 3 pockets were resent. Retransmitted counts those pockets that were being sent again, so if you have 5 and you keep resending all 5 at the time you will get 5 but if you send 3 at the time it will return 3.

Comment: Can you please rephrase it. i could not able to understand.

Comment: Did you mean that 5 packet which got lost is retransmitted as 3 packets  once RTO expires and tcpi_retrans counter get increment as 3

Comment: @sujaiMJ sorry for long wait, I forgot about this question, and yes that is what I meant.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.